# Javaee in intellij idea IDE

Tags: java, html, jsp, intellij-idea

I created a Java EE Web module in Intellij idea IDE and added jstl-1.2.jar into lib directory.
Also, I added this line to my jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

but I got this error: con not resolve taglibrary with the uri.

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [JSTL 1.1](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip) here and JSTL 1.2 [here](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar). and add to project.
And add `taglib lib` to project from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar);

Comment: you add taglib standard lib to project, [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar)

Answer (score 0):

you also need taglibs lib for that. see [that](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard/1.1.2)

Comment: Same as with jstl jar. WEB-INF/lib will be OK

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer from another page.
In Intellij idea IDE, all external files should be defined in the class path by going to:
Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies